# c# byte array => file => c++ array?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, binary, converters

So basically I was writing an OBJ parser ( in c++ ) and it worked well. But with bigger "meshes" it started to take almost 30 - 60 seconds to load it and that is not acceptable!

So I read that a binary reader was faster, which led to me making an obj => float[] parser in c#
and the float[] is what in c++ you would directly call to: glBufferData();

This is the code I use in c# to save to binary file ( I don't know if it is correct! ):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    struct Vector4f
    {
        public float x, y, z, w;
        public Vector4f(Vector4f o)
        {
            this.x = o.x;
            this.y = o.y;
            this.z = o.z;
            this.w = o.w;
        }
        public Vector4f(float x, float y, float z, float w)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.w = w;
        }
    };
    struct OBJFace
    {
        public Vector3f verts;
        public Vector3f norms;
        public Vector3f textures;

        public Vector4f verts4;
        public Vector4f norms4;
        public Vector4f textures4;
        public OBJFace(Vector3f v, Vector3f n, Vector3f t)
        {
            verts = v;
            norms = n;
            textures = t;
            verts4 = new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
            norms4 = new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
            textures4 = new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        public OBJFace(Vector4f v, Vector4f n, Vector4f t)
        {
            verts4 = v;
            norms4 = n;
            textures4 = t;
            verts = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
            norms = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
            textures = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
        }
    };
    struct OBJData
    {
        public int _pointCount;
        public List<OBJFace> F;
        public List<Vector3f> V;
        public List<Vector3f> VN;
        public List<Vector3f> VT;
        public int RenderID;
        public OBJData(int pc)
        {
            _pointCount = pc;
            RenderID = -1;
            this.F = new List<OBJFace>();
            this.V = new List<Vector3f>();
            this.VN = new List<Vector3f>();
            this.VT = new List<Vector3f>();
        }
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChooseFile_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog pfd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (pfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string file = pfd.FileName;
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pfd.FileName);
                OBJData d = new OBJData(4);
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (lines[i].StartsWith("v "))
                    {
                        Vector3f vec = new Vector3f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[3].Replace(".", ",")));
                        d.V.Add(vec);
                    }
                    else if (lines[i].StartsWith("vn "))
                    {
                        Vector3f norm = new Vector3f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[3].Replace(".", ",")));
                        d.VN.Add(norm);
                    }
                    else if (lines[i].StartsWith("vt "))
                    {
                        Vector3f text = new Vector3f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Replace(".", ",")), 0.0F);
                        d.VT.Add(text);
                    }else if(lines[i].StartsWith("f "))
                    {
                        Vector4f vert = new Vector4f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Split('/')[0].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Split('/')[0].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[3].Split('/')[0].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[4].Split('/')[0].Replace(".", ",")));
                        Vector4f norm = new Vector4f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Split('/')[2].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Split('/')[2].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[3].Split('/')[2].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[4].Split('/')[2].Replace(".", ",")));
                        Vector4f textures = new Vector4f((float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[1].Split('/')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[2].Split('/')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[3].Split('/')[1].Replace(".", ",")), (float)Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Split(' ')[4].Split('/')[1].Replace(".", ",")));
                        d.F.Add(new OBJFace(vert, norm, textures));
                    }
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("OBJ Parsing Done!");
                MessageBox.Show("OBJ Parsing Done, Continuing On To Converting!");

                List<float> vertices = new List<float>();
                for (int i = 0; i < d.F.Count; i++)
                {
                    OBJFace f = d.F[i];
                    Vector3f norms = d.VN[((int)f.norms4.x - 1)];
                    Vector3f textures = d.VT[((int)f.textures4.x - 1)];
                    Vector3f verts = d.V[((int)f.verts4.x - 1)];

                    Vector3f norms2 = d.VN[((int)f.norms4.y - 1)];
                    Vector3f textures2 = d.VT[((int)f.textures4.y - 1)];
                    Vector3f verts2 = d.V[((int)f.verts4.y - 1)];

                    Vector3f norms3 = d.VN[((int)f.norms4.z - 1)];
                    Vector3f textures3 = d.VT[((int)f.textures4.z - 1)];
                    Vector3f verts3 = d.V[((int)f.verts4.z - 1)];

                    Vector3f norms4 = d.VN[((int)f.norms4.w - 1)];
                    Vector3f textures4 = d.VT[((int)f.textures4.w - 1)];
                    Vector3f verts4 = d.V[((int)f.verts4.w - 1)];

                    float[] vertic ={
                            textures.x, textures.y,
                            norms.x, norms.y, norms.z,
                            verts.x, verts.y, verts.z,

                            textures2.x, textures2.y,
                            norms2.x, norms2.y, norms2.z,
                            verts2.x, verts2.y, verts2.z,

                            textures3.x, textures3.y,
                            norms3.x, norms3.y, norms3.z,
                            verts3.x, verts3.y, verts3.z,

                            textures4.x, textures4.y,
                            norms4.x, norms4.y, norms4.z,
                            verts4.x, verts4.y, verts4.z
                    };
                    for (int a = 0; a < vertic.Length; a++)
                    {
                        vertices.Add(vertic[a]);
                    }
                }
                float[] objArray = vertices.ToArray();
                Debug.WriteLine("Converting Done!");
                MessageBox.Show("Converting Done, Starting Save Back!");
                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    string sfile = sfd.FileName;
                    FileInfo sinfo = new FileInfo(sfile);
                    if (!sinfo.Exists)
                    {
                        byte[] byteArray = new byte[objArray.Length * 4];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(objArray, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(sfile, byteArray);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Save Back Completed!");
                        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("File: " + info.FullName + ", Doesn't Exist!");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know if this is correct but i tried to do as I do in c++.

**And My Question: How would I restore the objArray in c++ code to directly call do glBufferData(); ?, Is this even possible ? Is this code wrong?**

Also I noticed that it is super fast in c# with about 0.25 seconds, I don't really know why but I don't really care!

**Additional Question: Can you achieve this speed in c++ text reading aswell? if so how?**

Comment: If you want to read and write binary data as text, you should use [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: There's this nice `BinaryWriter.WriteArray` method that does all of that for you.  In C++, you can use `fopen` and `fread` to reconstitute it into a float array (or vector).  Or, you can even use memory-mapped I/O to get a pointer to the data, and pass that pointer directly to `glBufferData`.

Comment: Or, you can parse it in C++ and completely skip the C#.  Yes, C++ can be just as fast.  Just don't use `ifstream` for your parsing.

Comment: @BenVoigt
How would I go about doing this, I don't care if I have to skip c# just that it can load fast!

Can you explain what method I should use?

Comment: @RobanKrok: Personally I've found that a very fast method (I load text files with hundreds of megabytes of scientific research data) is to memory-map the file, use a pointer to scan through it.  Recognizing your prefixes by hand is pretty easy, I wouldn't even use a function for that since they're only 1-3 characters each.  For getting the numeric data, `strtol` and `strtod` are awesome.  They both get the value and update your pointer.

Comment: @RobanKrok: You might post a question with your C++ code, a small example data file, and ask how to make it run faster.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I will look into memory-mapping files, and if I encounter a problem I will do that. Thanks!